# Do HR find "custom" 1pg resume's more appealing then the regular?

Tags: professionalism, resume, hiring-process, human-resources

I am a computer science student, and will be doing my coop term soon. Although most companies don't mention it specifically, it has become the norm in the world that if you want to work for the "big tech" companies, you must have a 1 pg resume, or I've heard.

Since 1pg is very limited, people usually "photoshop" their resumes, move things around, and transform something like this:

[image]

into this:

[image]

My question goes out to employers specifically. If the content of the two resume's are the same, but one is more visually appealing, does this affect the hiring process? The microsoft word standard resume is widely used, but many students also have their resume's customed as in the second photo, and I wanted to see what employers think of the second one vs the first

Comment: See also [Are plain or attention grabbing résumés more effective?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/34828/are-plain-or-attention-grabbing-r%C3%A9sum%C3%A9s-more-effective)

Comment: NEVER use that second one especially the graphic at the bottom. I need to  be able to read what you have done not try to interpret some graph. Automated systems need to understand what you did.  Ugh. I would toss the second without reading it because you don't know what I need to decide to interview you. It might work if someone in their 20s was the hiring official but not anyone older than that. And for anyone above entry level, it wastes too much space that hiring officials would p[refer to be filled with content on what you have accomplished.

Comment: Don't put a picture of yourself either, unless it's an on-camera media job.. It opens yourself up to bias before they've even met you. It could be racial, sexism or even just reminding the recipient of someone they don't like. You only get one chance to make a first impression and you need to make it based on the real you, not a photograph. It could even cause a positive response you don't want like, "She's hot, I'm calling her for a face-to-face".

Comment: @ChristopherEstep Agreed.  Not only is it a bad idea, but (at least here in Canada) it's actually illegal for an employer to ask for a picture prior to a face-to-face interview, so including one on your resume, even voluntarily, is a bad idea.  Even employers who *aren't discriminatory* might feel squeamish about your resume if they know about such a law in your country.

Comment: @OP: I honestly feel like the whole "one page only" rule is kind of outdated these days, especially in computer-related fields.  Back in the day it was recommended because multiple pages might get separated and lost, and employers didn't want to read an essay to get an idea of who you are.  Nowadays, with resumes submitted in digital formats like PDF, and modern scanning software picking out the important keywords, having more than one page is not the sin it used to be.  I'd still say keep it as short and concise as you can, but don't get hung up on making it one page.